# letting script display time in top bar ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: python, gnome-shell, time

I wrote a little script in Python to show the current time in words and simultaneously in Norwegian. So i would like to display that in the top bar of Ubuntu 18.04 lts instead of the standard time. Thanks

Edit: And here is the script if that is useful:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import datetime

d2 = {0: 'Null', 1: 'En', 2: 'To', 3: 'Tre', 4: 'Fire', 5: 'Fem', 6: 'Seks', 7: 'Sju', 8: 'Åtte', 9: 'Ni', 10: 'Ti', 11: 'Elleve', 12: 'Tolv', 13: 'Tretten', 14: 'Fjorten', 15: 'Femten', 16: 'Seksten', 17: 'Sytten', 18: 'Atten', 19: 'Nitten', 20: 'Tjue', 21: 'Tjueen', 30: 'Tretti', 40: 'Førti', 50: 'Femti', 22: 'Tjueto', 23: 'Tjuetre', 24: 'Tjuefire', 25: 'Tjuefem', 26: 'Tjueseks', 27: 'Tjuesju', 28: 'Tjueåtte', 29: 'Tjueni', 31: 'Trettien', 32: 'Trettito', 33: 'Trettitre', 34:'Trettifire', 35: 'Trettifem', 36: 'Trettiseks', 37: 'Trettisju', 38: 'Trettiåtte', 39: 'Trettini', 41: 'Førtien', 42: 'Førtito', 43: 'Førtitre', 44: 'Førtifire', 45: 'Førtifem', 46: 'Førtiseks', 47: 'Førtisju', 48: 'Førtiåtte', 49: 'Førtini', 51: 'Femtien', 52: 'Femtito', 53: 'Femtitre', 54: 'Femtifire', 55: 'Femtifem', 56: 'Femtiseks', 57: 'Femtisju', 58: 'Femtiåtte', 59: 'Femtini'}

def time_round_to_5_minutes():

    minute = datetime.datetime.now().minute
    second = datetime.datetime.now().second

    if minute % 5 * 60 + second < 150:
        minute = minute - minute % 5
    else:
        minute = minute + 5 - minute % 5
        minute = minute % 60

    return minute

def time_in_norwegian():
    hour = (datetime.datetime.now().hour + 2) % 24
    minute = time_round_to_5_minutes()
    d2[0] = 'Midnatt'
    next_hour = True
    if minute % 30 <= 15:
        if minute == 45:
            string = 'Kvart på '
        elif minute == 30:
            string = 'Halv '
        elif minute == 0:
            next_hour = False
        elif minute < 20:
            string = d2[minute] + ' over '
            next_hour = False
            if minute == 15:
                string = 'Kvart over '
        else:
            string = d2[minute - 30] + ' over halv '
    else:
        if minute < 30:
            string = d2[30-minute] + ' på halv '
        else:
            string = d2[60-minute] + ' på '

    if next_hour == True:
        hour = (hour + 1) % 24
    if hour < 12:
        am_pm =  ' om morgenen'
    else:
        am_pm = ' om kvelden'
        hour = hour % 12
    string += d2[hour].lower() + am_pm


    return string

print(time_in_norwegian())
```

Comment: There are extensions allowing to change the appearance of the clock

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to display your custom output on the top bar in Gnome Shell is to use the high quality and well maintained [Gnome Shell extension Argos](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1176/argos/). Then you will need to remove the existing clock. The extension [Clock Override](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1206/clock-override/) allows to customize the format, so in your case you may have it display a space.

Perhaps [Clock Override](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1206/clock-override/) allows you to set a format close to what you want. That would eliminate the need for a custom script.

The final option is to go into the Gnome Shell code yourself, and create your own extension. That will require a learning curve to learn to programmatically interact with an ever changing and poorly documented interface, but that is what the many Gnome Shell extension developers do. The many existing extensions can help to study how things can be done.